ADMU3007E: Exception com.ibm.ws.process.exception.ProcessOpException: Access is denied
When trying to start WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment 9.0.5.13
I am getting the following error in log:
00000001 WsServerLaunc E   ADMU3002E: Exception attempting to process server server1
00000001 WsServerLaunc E   ADMU3007E: Exception com.ibm.ws.process.exception.ProcessOpException: com.ibm.ws.process.exception.ProcessOpException: Access is denied.
 005: Access is denied.

    at com.ibm.ws.process.Win32ProcessImpl.create(Win32ProcessImpl.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.process.ProcessFactory.create(ProcessFactory.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.launchProcess(LaunchCommand.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:335)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:281)

The full trace from CMD is as follows:
D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin>startServer server1
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\startServer.log
IBMJGSSProvider Build-Level: -20180404
[JGSS_DBG_PROV]  main IBMJGSSProvider (version 8.0) loaded
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
Time: [0x6717e227], Process: [20524], Thread: [0x5ee8]: Launch failed.  Error: [5] reported back to parent.
Time: [0x6717e227], Process: [20524], Thread: [0x5ee8]: Launch failed.  Error: [5] reported back to parent.
ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error:
           com.ibm.ws.process.exception.ProcessOpException:
           com.ibm.ws.process.exception.ProcessOpException: Access is denied.

           005: Access is denied.

any advise how to fix this issue ?

I discovered that the issue was related to the antivirus on the server and it corrupted some JRE files inside webspehere java folder.
